# Prevent running multiple scheduled tasks at a time/only one at a time (pause while other is running)

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

I have two scheduled tasks created using Quartz.NET library like following:

```
 public static void StartCompetitorResearchUpdate()
    {
        IJobDetail competitorResearch = JobBuilder.Create<CompetitorResearchJob>().WithIdentity("Job1").Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("Trigger1").StartNow().WithCronSchedule("0 0 0/2 * * ?").ForJob("Job1").Build();
        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler();
        sc.ScheduleJob(competitorResearch, trigger);
        sc.Start();
    }
    public static void StartStoreAnalyticsUpdate()
    {
        IJobDetail competitorResearch = JobBuilder.Create<StoreAnalyticsUsersUpdate>().WithIdentity("Job2").Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("Trigger2").StartAt(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow).WithCronSchedule("0 0 0/4 * * ?").ForJob("Job2").Build();
        ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        IScheduler sc = sf.GetScheduler();
        sc.ScheduleJob(competitorResearch, trigger);
        sc.Start();
    }
```

The trick here is that I'd like that first scheduled task StartCompetitorResearchUpdate() <= to pause for xx minutes ( preferrably like 20-30 minutes - or while 2nd job is running) because the first job can sometimes run 24/7 and theres  a lot of data to be pulled via HTTP requests, that's why  I need to pause the first one while 2nd one runs.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

P.S. the first job runs every 2 hours, and 2nd job runs every 4 hours...

Comment: Far better than to make a tiny _kickstart_ app that, invoked via _Windows Task Scheduler_, can hit a known URI on your web site _rather_ than making the web site have the concept of background jobs that are at the mercy of IIS AppPools or 3rd party libs.   Plus, Windows Task Scheduler does what you ask and more

Comment: @MickyD Ha good point ! Never thought of it like that .. I'll look into that solution, thanks ! :)

Comment: You are quite welcome good sir :)

Comment: @MickyD And happy new year :D

Comment: Happy New Year buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ITriggerListener` and implement the method [VetoJobExecution](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/2.0/html/html/55e01ac2-75ca-95e1-de6d-d08c120b7895.htm).
More informations can be found [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html).